# change default language of trac to german

Tags: trac

I installed trac v1.0.10.
The language of the trac-system (e.g. navigation) is English.

The content of the trac is in German. So how can I change the default_language to German, as well?

The default language of the server is German.

BR
Christian

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install Babel (python-babel in some package managers). Set [default_language](https://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/TracIni#trac-section) in the `[trac]` section of trac.ini.

After installing Babel you can set your session preference from the language preference page (`/prefs/language`). The `default_language` setting controls the default. If the language setting can't be changed, then the language catalogs haven't been compiled. Often it's necessary to uninstall Trac, install babel and then reinstall Trac. The point is, Babel must be installed when Trac is installed.

Comment: Thx RjOllos.

I tried to install babel and trac before, but it didn't work. Maybe the babel-version von github was the wrong one. Now I tried with the one from python: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Babel

Comment: Which version of Trac and such version of Babel? Some very recent versions of Babel may not work unless you have an unreleased version of Trac.

Comment: I tried Trac 1.0.10 with Babel 6.8.1 [link](https://github.com/babel/babel.git.) But this didnt't work. Trac 1.0.10 with Babel 2.3.4 is ok [link](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Babel)